# how can I use FirstOrDefault()?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have this code and I want to set a value to Viewdate when the expression returns no data:

```
ViewData["Fix"] = db.PreStatusViws.Where(c => c.LkpNameFix == "1").FirstOrDefault().NumCoefficientFix;
```

can I set zero or a "Text" for that? I no, what can I do?!
note: FirstOrDefault(null) cause an error.

Answer (score 7):

If I understand your question correctly, the following code should solve your problem:

```
var p = db.PreStatusViws.Where(c => c.LkpNameFix == "1").FirstOrDefault(); 
if(p != null)
    ViewData["Fix"] = p.NumCoefficientFix;
else
    ViewData["Fix"] = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you, So I had to always use if-else control? There is no way to set a default value for this case?

Comment: `ViewData["Fix"] = p.NumCoefficientFix ?? 0`

Answer (score 1):

Default will return the default for the data type.  If the data type in that place is a reference type (e.g. string) the default value will always be null, and therefore the following .NumsCoefficientFix member will throw a NullReferenceException.

The default value is built into .NET and not changeable, and is always given if the result set contains no value.

@Mikey has already given the code sample in his answer that I would suggest.

Answer (score 1):

If you first select the numeric column, FirstOrDefault will work as you intend, returning either a value or 0 (the default for numeric types):

```
ViewData["Fix"] = db.PreStatus
  .Select (c => c.NumCoefficientFix)
  .FirstOrDefault (c => c.LkpNameFox == "1");
```

If NumCoefficientFix is a nullable type, then use the ?? operator to convert the null into 0:

```
ViewData["Fix"] = db.PreStatus
  .Select (c => c.NumCoefficientFix)
  .FirstOrDefault (c => c.LkpNameFox == "1") ?? 0;
```

Selecting the NumCoefficientFix first is also (slightly) more efficient for LINQ-to-database queries, in that the SQL generated will select only that column.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to select your `NumCoefficientFix` property before calling `FirstOrDefault`:

```
ViewData["Fix"] = db.PreStatusViws
                    .Where(c => c.LkpNameFix == "1")
                    .Select(c => c.NumCoefficientFix)
                    .FirstOrDefault();`
```

Or in LINQ notation:

```
ViewData["Fix"] = (from c in db.PreStatusViws
                   where c.LkpNameFix == "1"
                   select c.NumCoefficientFix
                  ).FirstOrDefault();
```